# Initializing the added columns to a resizable 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, initialization

I want to increase the number of columns of a 2D vector. Here is my sample code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    vector < vector <double> > U (5, vector <double> (1, 0));
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 5; ii++)
    {
        U [ii] [0] = ii + 1;
    }
    U . resize (5, vector <double> (2));
    return 0;
}
```

This adds an uninitialized column to the vector U, but I need the new column be initialized to zero. How can I do this?

(I use Dev-C++ 5.6.3)

Comment: loop through the column and initialize it with zero...

Answer (score 1):

You will need to first resize any existing rows, changing the number of columns:

```
for(vector<double> & v : m)
  v.resize(v.cend(), <new column count>-<old column count>, 0);
```

After that you add any new rows:

```
m.insert(m.cend(), <new row count>-<old row count>, vector<double>(<new column count>, 0));
```